# Custom time AM,PM string format react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datetime, react-datepicker

I'm working with `react-datepicker` lib. I want custom 'AM, PM' text to 'SA, CH' (vietnam language).
Ex: `1:00 AM` to `1:00 SA`, `5:00 PM` to `5:00 CH`.
I try to import Vietnam locale but not work.

```
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from 'react-datepicker'
import viLocale from 'date-fns/locale/vi'
registerLocale('vi', viLocale)
...
<DatePicker
...
dateFormat="h:mm aa"
locale="vi"
/>
```

Any can help me. Thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dateFormat="h:mm aaaa"` instead of `dateFormat="h:mm aa"` like:

```
<DatePicker
  showTimeSelect
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
  dateFormat="h:mm aaaa"
  locale="vi"
/>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-roman-opk4e2?file=/src/index.js) for a live working example of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display it while selecting the time, do as follows:

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  dateFormat="h:mm aaaa"
  timeFormat="h:mm aaaa"
  locale="vi"
/>
```